# On edit trigger based on specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted my code to trigger only if the Value in cell ( L2) is " ADD" 
but the code doesn't seem to work ! do you mind let me know what I missed ?

```
function onEdit(e) { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var r = sheet.getRange("L2").getValue(); 
    if (r == "Add") { 
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet(); 
        var myValue=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M1").getDisplayValue(); 
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Daily Report " + myValue); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify if the condition is for "ADD" (all caps) or "Add"? In your OP, you've asked for the word "ADD" (all caps) but your code has it as "Add".

Also, please consider editing your original post and adding the code there :) It works perfectly if you update the cell with "Add", instead of "ADD".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, note that onEdit() trigger fires whenever a user makes an edit on any page.  It's your responsibility in the code to narrow the scope of the triggers effect.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sh=e.range.getSheet(); 
  var r=sh.getRange("L2").getValue(); 
  if (r.toLowerCase()=="add" && sh.getName()=="TheNameOfTheSheetYouWantThisToWorkIn") { 
    e.source.duplicateActiveSheet(); 
    var myValue=sh.getRange("M1").getDisplayValue(); 
    e.source.renameActiveSheet("Daily Report " + myValue); 
  }
}
```

[Read about simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
[Learn more about onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)